# Java - Override @bean function to pick AWS Credentials from properties file

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I already have a config file which is as below:

```
@Configuration
public class CloudConfig {

    @Value("${aws.region}")
    private String awsRegion;
    
    @Value("${aws.accessKeyId}")
    private String awsAccessKeyId;
    
    @Value("${aws.awsSecretKeyId}")
    private String awsSecretKeyId;

    @Bean
    public AmazonSNS amazonSnsClient() {
        return AmazonSNSClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(awsRegion).withCredentials(AWSCredentials()).build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public AWSCredentialsProvider aWSCredentials() {        
        return new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKeyId, awsSecretKeyId));
    }
}
```

I have an application properties file that has AWS properties of multiple environments in one file

```
#DEV
abc.env[0].aws.accessKeyId=xaw
abc.env[0].aws.awsSecretKeyId=yrt

#TEST
abc.env[1].aws.accessKeyId=abc
abc.env[1].aws.awsSecretKeyId=def
```

Based on some parameters I need to pick the AWS Credentials from a properties file

Is there any way I can override @bean values depending on some condition? ex. If x picks dev credentials if y picks test credentials in spring boot

Since I already have a config file, I'm not sure How can I override the @Bean in config so it can pick up the correct AWS credentials from the property file based on parameters.

**Note:** The requirement is that the properties of Dev and Test has to be in one file

Can someone please help?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Switching between multiple sets of AWS credentials is exactly what the `AWS_PROFILE` environment variable does.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html  This will work with the default credential provider chain.

Comment: I second @DanielFarrell suggestion but also this is also a use case for Spring Boot profiles.  If you don't want to use AWS_PROFILES you can create a variety of `application-${profile}.properties` files with differing AWS keys then use -Dspring.profiles.active=${profile} when running your jar.  They should not be in the same properties files

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli Agreed. However, the requirement is they have to be in the same properties file.

Comment: Thats a non-requirement ( IE its not telling you what needs to be, but how ).  If you turn it into a yaml file I think it can technically be "one" file - but again that's not how you would accomplish this in spring boot with a properties files.  Spring's solution to this is the use of Spring Profile and that requires multiple properties files ( or can be a single yaml file I believe )

Comment: Is there any way I can override @bean values depending on some condition? ex. If x picks dev credentials if y picks test credentials in spring boot

Comment: @SwetaSharma how do you want x to pick the different values?  Via a command line argument or sometime after the application is bootstrapped?

Comment: sometime after the application is bootstrapped.

Comment: @DanielFarrell How can I switch profile after the application is bootstrapped?